# JavaFX System out Println

Tags: java, javafx

I'm doing an interface to show the progress of my simulation (elevators simulating job on a building). 
The thing is, I already did this on the console with `System.out.println()`s and I wanted to show the exact same thing on a javaFX window. Is there any way where I can set the text of a `TextArea` or a `Label` or something to match the output of the console? Just printing the same thing but instead of printing on the console I wanted to print on a window. 
I was dumb enough to try and set the Text of a `TextArea`to the `toString()` of my simulator but ofc if it is `System.out.println()`, it shows on the console and not in the `ThextArea`.

EDIT: This is what I want to print:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    for (int y = 0; y < 50; y++) {
        System.out.println("");
    }

    for (int i = pisos.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(pisos.get(i).getPiso());
        System.out.print(pisos.get(i).pQueue().toString());
        System.out.print(" " + percorrerElevadores2(i));
        System.out.print(" " + pisos.get(i).pessoasServidas() + "\n");
    }

    System.out.println("Numero total de passageiros à espera:" + " " + Predio.getPredio().getNPessoasEmEspera());
    System.out.println("Numero total de pessageiros servidos:" + " " + Predio.getPredio().getNPessoasServidas());
    for (int z = 0; z < getElevadores().size(); z++) {
        System.out.println("Distancia percorrida pelo elevador" + " " + z + ":" + " " + Predio.getPredio().getElevadores().get(z).getDistanciaPercorrida() + " " + "Pisos");
        System.out.println("Piso destino do elevador" + " " + z + ":" + " " + Predio.getPredio().getElevadores().get(z).getPisoDestino());
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: don't override toString for application reasons ... ever! Instead, access object properties and format them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the MessageDialogBox to print the message on window with reference of the panel on which you are working.

Comment: It rather fit for comment, not an answer to the question. Please edit and elaborate your answer with the process in details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question but it would be easier to rename the println calls than to redirect them.  Use some code like this in your main class (the one that extends Application) or really in any class, but you need to add the textArea to the scene graph somewhere.

```
private static final TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
//add textArea to your scene somewhere in the start method
public static void println(String s){
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {//in case you call from other thread
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+s+"\n");
            System.out.println(s);//for echo if you want
        }
    });
}
```

Then just use the IDE's search and replace to rename System.out.println to MainClassName.println.

Comment: im using scene builder so i dont need to start the textArea that way, but ill try that static void println.

Comment: i tried that, it "tries" to print something , it prints the output on console and the textArea remains blank, but the scroll moves down so im betting that i cant have those System out println :S

Comment: or maybe the problem is i have print and println.

Comment: ok its printing now but its not formated, i tried to change ur code to print instead of println , maybe thats the error

Comment: now it works perfectly but when i call this from a thread it breaks the program :S

Comment: It won't work exactly like println, that does things like object.toString().  I don't know about the threading, for swing I would use `if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
            txtArea.append(text + lineSep);
        } else {//runlater}` but I didn't think it was needed.

Comment: After looking at old swing code I realized TextArea also has an appendText(String) method, don't forget the linefeed.

Comment: i just fint the problem. whenever i try to start a thread from any button on JAVAfx , everything crashes :O i cant fix it :S

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you just want to print text in a location to investigate things, ie the results. Everything you want is just like you print a text on the console, you also want to print this text somewhere in a JavaFX application. Despite its formatting done in their toString method, you can catch the return of the method and print to a JavaFX application (within a control node, for example), right?

If this is the case ...

I created a simple application that works with two text areas. In the middle of application, you will find buttons that manipulate both areas. Basically, the buttons sends the contents of a text area to another. Note:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AreaTextual extends Application 
{
// #########################################################################################################
//                                                                                                      MAIN
// #########################################################################################################

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Application.launch(args);
}

// #########################################################################################################
//                                                                                                INSTÂNCIAS
// #########################################################################################################

// Controles.

private Label lab_receptor;
private Label lab_emissor;

private TextArea tArea_receptor;
private TextArea tArea_emissor;

private Button bot_enviar;
private Button bot_enviarLinha;
private Button bot_substituir;
private Button bot_apagar;

// Layout.

private HBox hbox_raiz;

private VBox vbox_oeste;
private VBox vbox_centro;
private VBox vbox_leste;

// #########################################################################################################
//                                                                                                 INÍCIO FX
// #########################################################################################################

@Override public void start(Stage estagio) throws Exception 
{
    this.iniFX();
    this.confFX();
    this.adFX();
    this.evFX();

    Scene cenario = new Scene(this.hbox_raiz , 640 , 480);

    estagio.setScene(cenario);
    estagio.setTitle("Programa JavaFX");
    estagio.show();
}

/** Inicia nós FX.*/
protected void iniFX()
{
    // Controles.

    this.lab_receptor = new Label();
    this.lab_emissor = new Label();

    this.tArea_receptor = new TextArea();
    this.tArea_emissor = new TextArea();

    this.bot_enviar = new Button();
    this.bot_enviarLinha = new Button();
    this.bot_substituir = new Button();
    this.bot_apagar = new Button();

    // Layout.

    this.hbox_raiz = new HBox();

    this.vbox_oeste = new VBox();
    this.vbox_centro = new VBox();
    this.vbox_leste = new VBox();
}

/** Configura nós FX.*/
protected void confFX()
{
    // Controles.

    this.lab_receptor.setText("RECEPTOR");
    this.lab_receptor.setFont(new Font(32));

    this.lab_emissor.setText("EMISSOR");
    this.lab_emissor.setFont(new Font(32));

    this.bot_enviar.setText("<- ENVIAR");
    this.bot_enviar.setPrefSize(150 , 60);

    this.bot_enviarLinha.setText("<- ENVIAR+");
    this.bot_enviarLinha.setPrefSize(150 , 60);

    this.bot_substituir.setText("<- SUBSTITUIR");
    this.bot_substituir.setPrefSize(150 , 60);

    this.bot_apagar.setText("<- APAGAR TUDO ->");
    this.bot_apagar.setPrefSize(150 , 60);

    // Layout.

    this.hbox_raiz.setSpacing(20);
    this.hbox_raiz.setPadding(new Insets(30 , 30 , 30 , 30));
    this.hbox_raiz.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    this.vbox_oeste.setSpacing(10);
    this.vbox_oeste.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    this.vbox_centro.setSpacing(10);
    this.vbox_centro.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    this.vbox_centro.setPrefSize(400 , 200);

    this.vbox_leste.setSpacing(10);
    this.vbox_leste.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
}

/** Adiciona e organiza em layout os nós FX.*/
protected void adFX()
{
    this.vbox_leste.getChildren().addAll(this.lab_emissor , this.tArea_emissor);
    this.vbox_centro.getChildren().addAll(this.bot_enviar , this.bot_enviarLinha , this.bot_substituir , this.bot_apagar);
    this.vbox_oeste.getChildren().addAll(this.lab_receptor , this.tArea_receptor);

    this.hbox_raiz.getChildren().addAll(this.vbox_oeste , this.vbox_centro , this.vbox_leste);
}

/** Configura eventos de nós FX.*/
protected void evFX()
{
    this.bot_enviar.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            tArea_receptor.appendText(tArea_emissor.getText());
        }
    });

    this.bot_enviarLinha.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            tArea_receptor.appendText(String.format("%n%s" , tArea_emissor.getText()));
        }
    });

    this.bot_substituir.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            tArea_receptor.replaceText(0 , tArea_receptor.getLength() , tArea_emissor.getText());
        }
    });

    this.bot_apagar.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            tArea_receptor.setText("");
            tArea_emissor.setText("");
        }
    });
}
}
```

**OBS** (**PT-BR**): Eu notei que você fala português, portanto deixei o código na linguagem para que você entenda-o melhor.

This class has nothing exceptional. It just shows you how you can manipulate the text of a TextArea. You can find other types of handlers of a TextArea right [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html), and also [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html).

Regarding your problem seen where you call the JavaFX methods from another thread, this can be happening just because you're not using the JavaFX Application Thread. Like the Swing library has the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), JavaFX also has its own thread responsible for handling the JavaFX elements. Whenever you need to manipulate any JavaFX element, be to setup something or to obtain some data, you need to do this using the JavaFX Application Thread, and not another.

For you to call methods of the JavaFX Application Thread, use the [Platform](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html) [runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method. For more information about the JavaFX threads system, visit the following links:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/architecture/jfxpub-architecture.htm

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

In the first link, read the part that talks about threads. If you have any more questions, come back here and ask.

Good luck.

Comment: hey ! thanks for your help mate ! your code was really helpfull, but i redefined the System.out.println method so it appears on the textArea too! my only problem now is that the javaFX crashes when i start the thread. i tried to use the platform.runLater method to initialize the thread but  still it crashes the application. EDIT: i run my thread like this: Platform.runLater(myThread);

Comment: A JavaFX application should start from the main thread with a call to the launch method of the Application class. I think maybe you're not starting your JavaFX application correctly. Actually, I have no idea what you mean when you mention that your application crashes when you "start the thread." You are actually starting your application the right way? What is the thread that is giving problem? What kind of error is appearing for you?

Comment: So i can run my javaFX application, and it has a button whose action starts another thread (not a javaFX thread). my controller observes that thread and whenever that thread do a certain action, it updates my textArea text. the problem is when i click on the button to start that thread, the program just freezes. no error, just freezes :S

Comment: What do you mean by "my controller observes that thread"? Your control node should not observe anything. By pressing a button to perform a job, a new thread is put to work for the realization of something that has nothing to do with JavaFX application. This means that when the button is clicked, the JavaFX Application Thread must remain free to do other things. Once the work is completed, the results of this work should be shown in your JavaFX application using JavaFX Application Thread. Do not be creating threads whenever the button is clicked. I suggest you to use an executor service.